# Python-push and pop from list at the same time

Tags: python

I have a list and while I constantly append element to it, I want to check that it isn't empty and get element at the same time. Normally we wait all the elements append to the list and then we get element from list do something. In this case, we lose some time for waiting all elements add to the list. What knowledge do I need to acquire to make this happen (Multiprocessing, multiprocessing.dummy, asynchronous) ,sorry, I am still new for doing this, I think it's better for me to explain to you why I want to achieve this kind of effect,this problem came from a web crawler

```
import requests
from model import Document    

def add_concrete_content(input_list):
    """input_list data structure [{'url': 'xxx', 'title': 'xxx'}...]"""
    for e in input_list:
        r = requests.get(e['url'])
        html = r.content
        e['html'] = html
    return input_list

def save(input_list):
    for e in input_list:
        Document.create(**e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = add_concrete_content(list)
    save(res)
    """this is I normally do, I save data to mysql or whatever database,but 
    I think the drawback is I have to wait all the html add to dict and then 
    save to database, what if I have to deal with tons of data? Can I save 
    the dict with the html first? Can I save some time? A friend of mine 
    said this is a typical producer consumer problem, probably gonna use 
    at least two threads and lock, because without lock, data probably 
    gonna fall into disorder"""
```

Comment: Please, include your code in your post directly instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Also, you don't necessarily have to use pop(which also removes the element from the list). In python you can simply use the list[index] syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're being vague. And I think there's a misconception in the way you want things to happen.

You don't need any extra python rock-science to do what you want:

- you can check if the list is empty by simply doing: `if list_:` (where `list_` is your list)
- you can verify any element by using `list_[idx]` (where idx is the index of the element). For example, `list_[0]` will get you the first element of the list, while `list_[-1]`, the last one.

That said, you don't have to wait for all the elements to be added to the list if you need to process them on the go. You might look for something like this:

```
def push(list_):
    count = 0
    while True:
        list_.append(count)
        f()
        count += 1
        if count == 1000:
            break


def f():
    print('First element: {}'.format(list_[0]))
    print('Last  element: {}'.format(list_[-1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_ = []
    push(list_)
```